# update jsonb data in PostgreSQL using where condition

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

My table "Item" has two columns id and value, value is a jsonb and its value is as

```
{
"id": "0030e363-bd50-4c68-a127-07c8a6a35c47",
"fields": [
    {
        "value": "14",
        "field_title": "Code"
    },
    {
        "value": "name1",
        "field_title": "Name"
    },
    {
        "value": "452",
        "field_title": "Title"
    }
]
}
```

How do I update value field in "fields" where "field_title" = "Code" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSONB_SET()` function after extract the elements of the array `fields` while determining the respective indexes such as

```
WITH f AS
(
 SELECT ('{fields,'||idx-1||',value}')::text[] AS path
   FROM tab 
  CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(value->'fields') 
   WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
  WHERE j->>'field_title'='Code' 
)
UPDATE tab
   SET value = JSONB_SET(value,f.path,'"1444"',false)
  FROM f;

SELECT value FROM tab;

value
-------------------------------
{
"id": "0030e363-bd50-4c68-a127-07c8a6a35c47",
"fields": [
    {
        "value": "1444",
        "field_title": "Code"
    },
    {
        "value": "name1",
        "field_title": "Name"
    },
    {
        "value": "452",
        "field_title": "Title"
    }
]
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c35c0f401e48a334f410996a1f4aa1a8)</kbd>